# dji drone set obstacles avoidance distance

Tags: android, dji-sdk

we are working on an Android app using the dji sdk, we use a mavic 2 pro drone.
We need to set the collision distance active between 0 and 75cm, we tried to use this method https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/IntelligentFlightAssistant/DJIIntelligentFlightAssistant.html#djiintelligentflightassistant_setvisualobstaclesavoidancedistance_inline , but we get the error "The feature is unsupported" .
How can we solve the issue?
Thank you